# map() as a callback in setState() in React running the conditional twice oddly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am loading an array of objects into the state of a component. Here's what the array is

```
const toDoData = [
    {
        id:1,
        task:"Take out trash",
        completed : false
    },
    {
        id:2,
        task:"Wash the dishes",
        completed : true
    },
    {
        id:3,
        task:"Do groceries",
        completed : false
    },
```

I load it into the state as;

```
this.state={
     data:toDoData
 }
```

I want to change the boolean value of object.completed by clicking a button and I do this by updating the state in the following way;

```
changeStatus(id){


        this.setState(prev=>{

            const updatedtodo=prev.todo.map(todo=>{
                if(todo.id==id){
                    todo.completed = ! todo.completed
                    console.log(todo.completed)
                }
                return todo
            })

        return{
            todo:updatedtodo
        }    
        })    
    }
```

but the conditional statement in this ends up running twice for some reason (the console.log statements displays twice), which sets the boolean value back to its original. Could someone enlighten me why that is? and how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the editing. I am new to this website actually. Will post questions in better format next time

Answer (score 2):

```
changeStatus(id){


    this.setState(prev=>{
        const clonePrev = {...prev};
        const updatedtodo=clonePrev.todo.map(todo=>{
            if(todo.id==id){
                todo.completed = ! todo.completed
                console.log(todo.completed)
            }
            return todo
        })

    return{
        todo:updatedtodo
    }    
    })    
}
```

Comment: Just cloned prev and mapping on that.

Comment: const clonePrev = {...prev};
const updatedtodo=clonePrev.

Comment: its still looping through the if statement twice. i don't understand why that might be happening. Maybe the bug is elsewhere in the code?